# Reformat the string in text file and reprint out into another text file Java?

Tags: java, string, text, text-files

The string in the text file are like this:

```
    Fulton County 6
    County Grand 1
    Grand Jury 2
    Jury said 1
    said Friday 4
    Friday an 1
    an investigation 5
    investigation of 15
    of Atlanta's 1
    Atlanta's recent 1
    recent primary 1
    primary election 2
    election produced 1
    produced `` 1
    `` no 6
```

I want to read from it and reprint into another text file in the format as below:

```
    Fulton County           6
    County Grand            1
    Grand Jury              2
    Jury said               1
    said Friday             4
    Friday an               1
    an investigation        5
    investigation of        15
    of Atlanta's            1
    Atlanta's recent        1
    recent primary          1
    primary election        2
    election produced       1
    produced ``             1
    `` no                   6
```

Comment: Good idea. It will be more readable. Do you have a question?

Comment: This is stupid because if you need to have a readable file go to json or XML.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **StringUtils** from apache commons lang - check this http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html and specifically serious of **rightPad** metehods

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [String .replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) with regexp " (\d+)"
and then replacing it with a string containing \t + digit for tabs